# Правильно ли написано предложение?

Tags: синтаксис

**Обои в горизонтальную полоску способны решить проблему многих людей – небольшая площадь комнаты.**

Comment: Нужно ли было менять метку «Орфография» на «Синтаксис»?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь как минимум непонятен смысл.

Если автор думает что обои действительно что-то способны решить, а проблема эта называется "небольшая площадь комнаты" то наверное надо согласование использовать.

*Обои в горизонтальную полоску способны решить проблему многих людей – небольшую площадь комнаты.*

По аналогии с конструкциями типа *"Лампа дневного света способна решить проблему многих – слабую освещенность рабочего места"*.

Но я не уверен, что автор имел в виду именно это. Даже если угадал, все равно надо перестраивать фразу. Стилистически неряшливая.

По минимуму так: 
*"Обои в горизонтальную полоску способны решить проблему многих людей – **ощущение** небольшой площади комнаты."*

Comment: Мне кажется, корректней говорить либо (1) малая плошадь - проблема комнаты, слабая освещенность - проблема рабочего места, либо (2) проблема человека - малая площадь ЕГО комнаты, слабая освещенность ЕГО рабочего места. Моя проблема - как-то  неуютно мне без этого слова "ЕГО" :)))

Answer (score 1):

Преследующий рекламные цели текст допускает превращение решения одной локальной задачи в средство от всех проблем. Зачастую, чем абсурднее логика таких выражений, тем они более «цепляют» потенциального покупателя. И если правка фразы (с обоями в полоску) не приведёт к конфликту с маркетологом, только тогда надо это сделать, понимая, что проблема кроется в нескольких факторах, вызывающих дискомфорт. Здесь же предлагаю отчасти смягчить категоричность высказывания:

*Обои в горизонтальную полоску успешно решат проблему малых по площади помещений*.

Comment: По-моему, предложенный @shampar вариант хорош не тем, что "смягчает", а тем, что исправляет логику предложения. Анна пишет, что проблема в том, что площадь комнаты мала. Эту   проблему обои не решают (не увеличивают площадь). А если написать о "проблеме малых по площади помещений", то тут каждый волен понимать по-своему. Например, я считаю, что проблемой малых по площади помещений является ощущение сдавленности, и обои в полоску эту проблему решают.